# Get the ratio of first two non zero value from a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

Here is my data frame **df**

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 2    2    5    6
 0    0    8    10
 0    1    1    5
 0    5    8    11
```

I'm expecting something like this

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4  ratio
     2    2    5    6   (2/2)
     0    0    8    10  (8/10)
     0    1    1    5   (1/1)
     0    5    8    11  (5/8)
```

this is what I have tried

```
a=function(x){
  w=dff1_redu[which(dff1_redu > 0),]
  sum(w[1:2])
}
 apply(dff1,1,sum[1:2],a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
df$ratio <- apply(df, 1, FUN= function(x) {x1 <- x[x!=0]
                                             x1[1]/x1[2]})
df$ratio
#[1] 1.000 0.800 1.000 0.625
```